# How is it decided if print uses a prefix

Tags: r

I'm wondering about a very basic behaviour of the `print()` function for which I was unable to find an explanation.

If I add a `name()` to my vector, I don't get a prefix (`[1]`). Minimal example:

```
x <- 1
names(x) <- "name"
print(x)

y<-2
print(y)
```

Output:

```
print(x)
```

> name
>
> 1

and

```
print(y)
```

> [1] 2

I was wondering if `names()` changes the class or something like by adding the attribute. But `typeof()` and `class()` do provide the same value for x and y. So I think it is the `print()` function, which does not give a prefix as output when an attribute is given. When does `print()` use the prefix `[x]` and when does it not?

Comment: `x` is named while `y` isn't hence different print methods are evoked. I think `x` is using `print.table` but not entirely sure how you can get which method was used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case object x is a numeric vector and has no attributes. In the second - object y is also a numeric vector, but has an attribute "names":

```
x <- 1
attributes(x)
# NULL

y <- 1
names(y) <- "value"
attributes(y)
# $`names`
# [1] "value"
```

In both cases print.default() method is used to display the value of an object. This function calls `.Internal(print.default(x, digits, quote, na.print, print.gap, 
        right, max, useSource, noOpt))`.

Looking at the source code of this function (for example here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/print.c) we can see that depending on whether the vector has attributes or not the output contains indexes of the first elements on each output line or not:

```
if((dims = getAttrib(s, R_DimSymbol)) != R_NilValue && length(dims) > 1) {
   ...
}
else { // no dim()
...
   sprintf(ptag, "[[%d]]", i+1);
...
}
```